# Javascript Output is NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having problems with my JavaScript. I build a form with the Bootstrap `stepper` function to build a product configurator. The price needs to be calculated by selected options from users, i want to do this in JavaScript because I want to do real time calculations so customers could see directly the price changing.

The problem is i get a `NaN` error at the output.

If I only use `getPootPrijs(poot)` of `getKleurPrijs(kleur)` in the `calculateTotal` function the calculation is done correctly on 1 step of the form. If I do both steps I get as a result `NaN`.

```js
//poot berekenen
var poot_prices = new Array();
poot_prices["poot1"] = 20.75;
poot_prices["poot2"] = 25;
poot_prices["poot3"] = 35;

function getPootPrijs(poot) {
  var pootRadio = document.getElementsByName('selectedOption');

  for (i = 0; i < pootRadio.length; i++) {
    if (pootRadio[i].checked) {
      user_input = pootRadio[i].value;
    }
  }

  return poot_prices[poot];
}

//kleur berekenen
var kleur_prices = new Array();
kleur_prices["kleur1"] = 5;
kleur_prices["kleur2"] = 10;
kleur_prices["kleur3"] = 15;
kleur_prices["kleur4"] = 20;
kleur_prices["kleur5"] = 25;
kleur_prices["kleur6"] = 30;

function getKleurPrijs(kleur) {
  var kleurRadio = document.getElementsByName('selectedOptionTwo');

  for (i = 0; i < kleurRadio.length; i++) {
    if (kleurRadio[i].checked) {
      user_input = kleurRadio[i].value;
    }
  }
  return kleur_prices[kleur];
}

function calculateTotal(poot, kleur) {
  var total = 29.95 + getPootPrijs(poot) + getKleurPrijs(kleur);
  var totalEl = document.getElementById('totalPrice');

  document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "Totale maandprijs: €" + total;
  totalEl.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div class="row pt-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="col-md-1 pl-5 pl-md-0 pb-5">
    <!-- Stepper -->
    <div class="steps-form-3">
      <div class="steps-row-3 setup-panel-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div class="steps-step-3">
          <a href="#step-5" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle-3 waves-effect ml-0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hoofbord"><i class="fa fa-chalkboard" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="steps-step-3">
          <a href="#step-6" type="button" class="btn btn-pink btn-circle-3 waves-effect p-3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Kleur"><i class="fa fa-palette" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="steps-step-3">
          <a href="#step-7" type="button" class="btn btn-pink btn-circle-3 waves-effect" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Afmeting"><i class="fa fa-weight" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="steps-step-3">
          <a href="#step-8" type="button" class="btn btn-pink btn-circle-3 waves-effect p-3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Matras"><i class="fa fa-bed" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="steps-step-3">
          <a href="#step-9" type="button" class="btn btn-pink btn-circle-3 waves-effect p-3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Aanvraag afronden"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Grid column -->

  <!-- Grid column -->
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <form role="form" action="output.php" method="post">
      <!-- First Step -->
      <div class="row setup-content-3" id="step-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3 class="font-weight-bold pl-0 my-4"><strong>Soort Poot</strong></h3>
          <p>Poten zijn er in diverse soorten en maten. Welk soort poot wilt u??</p>

          <div class="form-group md-form">
            <ul>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='poot1' name='selectedOption' id='poot1' required/>
                <label for='poot1'><img src="bed1.jpg" style="height: 100px;" onclick="calculateTotal('poot1')"></img></label>
              </li2>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='poot2' name='selectedOption' id='poot2' />
                <label for='poot2'><img src="bed2.jpg" style="height: 100px;" onclick="calculateTotal('poot2')"></img></label>
              </li2>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='poot3' name='selectedOption' id='poot3' />
                <label for='poot3'><img src="bed3.jpg" style="height: 100px;" onclick="calculateTotal('poot3')"></img></label>
              </li2>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-rounded nextBtn-3 float-right" type="button">Volgende</button>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!-- Second Step -->
      <div class="row setup-content-3" id="step-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3 class="font-weight-bold pl-0 my-4"><strong>Bekleding en kleur</strong></h3>

          <div class="form-group md-form">
            <ul>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='kleur1' name='selectedOptionTwo' id='kleur1' required/>
                <label for='kleur1'><img src="bed1.jpg" style="height: 100px;" onclick="calculateTotal('kleur1')"></img></label><br>
              </li2>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='kleur2' name='selectedOptionTwo' id='kleur2' />
                <label for='kleur2'><img src="bed2.jpg" style="height: 100px;" onclick="calculateTotal('kleur2')"></img></label><br>
              </li2>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='kleur3' name='selectedOptionTwo' id='kleur3' />
                <label for='kleur3'><img src="bed3.jpg" style="height: 100px;" onclick="calculateTotal('kleur3')"></img></label><br>
              </li2><br>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='kleur4' name='selectedOptionTwo' id='kleur4' />
                <label for='kleur4'><img src="bed2.jpg" style="height: 100px;" onclick="calculateTotal('kleur4')"></img></label><br>
              </li2>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='kleur5' name='selectedOptionTwo' id='kleur5' />
                <label for='kleur5'><img src="bed3.jpg" style="height: 100px;" onclick="calculateTotal('kleur5')"></img></label><br>
              </li2>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='kleur6' name='selectedOptionTwo' id='kleur6' />
                <label for='kleur6'><img src="bed3.jpg" style="height: 100px;" onclick="calculateTotal('kleur6')"></img></label><br>
              </li2>
            </ul>
          </div><br><br>
          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded prevBtn-3 float-left" type="button">Vorige</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-rounded nextBtn-3 float-right" type="button">Volgende</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Third Step -->
      <div class="row setup-content-3" id="step-7">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3 class="font-weight-bold pl-0 my-4"><strong>Breedte en lengte:</strong></h3>
          <div class="form-check">
            <ul>
              <li2>
                <div class="col">
                  <p>Breedte:</p>
                </div>
                <input type='radio' value='220cm' name='breedte' id='breedte1' required/>
                <label for='breedte1'><img src="bed1.jpg" style="height: 100px;"></img></label><br>
              </li2>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='breedte2' name='breedte' id='breedte2' />
                <label for='breedte2'><img src="bed2.jpg" style="height: 100px;"></img></label><br>
              </li2>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='breedte3' name='breedte' id='breedte3' />
                <label for='breedte3'><img src="bed3.jpg" style="height: 100px;"></img></label><br>
              </li2>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='breedte4' name='breedte' id='breedte4' />
                <label for='breedte4'><img src="bed2.jpg" style="height: 100px;"></img></label>
              </li2>
            </ul><br>
            <ul>
              <li2>
                <div class="col">
                  <p>Lengte:</p>
                </div>
                <input type='radio' value='lengte1' name='lengte' id='lengte1' required/>
                <label for='lengte1'><img src="bed1.jpg" style="height: 100px;"></img></label><br>
              </li2>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='lengte2' name='lengte' id='lengte2' />
                <label for='lengte2'><img src="bed2.jpg" style="height: 100px;"></img></label><br>
              </li2>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='lengte3' name='lengte' id='lengte3' />
                <label for='lengte3'><img src="bed3.jpg" style="height: 100px;"></img></label><br>
              </li2>
              <li2>
                <input type='radio' value='lengte4' name='lengte' id='lengte4' />
                <label for='lengte4'><img src="bed2.jpg" style="height: 100px;"></img></label>
              </li2>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded prevBtn-3 float-left" type="button">Vorige</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-rounded nextBtn-3 float-right" type="button">Volgende</button>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!-- Fourth Step -->
      <div class="row setup-content-3" id="step-8">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3 class="font-weight-bold pl-0 my-4"><strong>Keuze 5:</strong></h3>
          <ul>
            <li2>
              <input type='radio' value='matras1' name='matras' id='matras1' required/>
              <label for='matras1'><img src="bed1.jpg" style="height: 100px;"></img></label><br>
            </li2>
            <li2>
              <input type='radio' value='matras2' name='matras' id='matras2' />
              <label for='matras2'><img src="bed2.jpg" style="height: 100px;"></img></label><br>
            </li2>
            <li2>
              <input type='radio' value='matras3' name='matras' id='matras3' />
              <label for='matras3'><img src="bed3.jpg" style="height: 100px;"></img></label>
            </li2>
          </ul><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded prevBtn-3 float-left" type="button">Vorige</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-rounded nextBtn-3 float-right" type="button">Volgende</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Vijfde stap -->
      <div class="row setup-content-3" id="step-9">
        <div class="col-md-12">

          <h2 class="text-center font-weight-bold my-4">Configuratie compleet. Vul uw gegevens in om te bestellen.</h2><br>
          <h4><b>Uw maandbedrag</b>
            <div id="totalPrice"></div>
          </h4><br><br>


          <tr>
            <td colspan="1">
              <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group float-left">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Voornaam</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span><input id="voornaam" name="voornaam" placeholder="Uw Voornaam" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group float-right">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Achternaam</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="achternaam" name="achternaam" placeholder="Uw Achternaam" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group float-left">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Straat</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="straatnaam" name="straatnaam" placeholder="Straatnaam" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group float-right">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Huisnummer</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="huisnummer" name="huisnummer" placeholder="voorbeeld: 36" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group float-left">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Postcode</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="1234AB" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group float-right">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Plaatsnaam</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="plaatsnaam" name="plaatsnaam" placeholder="Plaatsnaam" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group float-left">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Telefoonnummer</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span><input id="telefoonnummer" name="telefoonnummer" placeholder="0612345678" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group float-right">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span><input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group float-left">
                  <label class="col-md-12 control-label">Gaat u akkoord met de algemene voorwaarden?</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span><input id="algemenevoorwaarden" name="algemenevoorwaarden" placeholder="algemenevoorwaarden" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="checkbox"
                        style="max-width:15px;"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </td>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded prevBtn-3 float-left" type="button">Vorige</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-rounded float-right" type="submit">Bestel</button>
        </div>
      </div><br><br>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Grid column -->
</div>
```

I hope someone could help me further with this.

Comment: `console.log calculateTotal;` is not valid javascript. What line do you get the reference error in?

Comment: at first glance, i can already see you defined the console log wrong (which should be `console.log(calculateTotal);` also the `CalculateTotal` var you put in there doesnt match on what i see, since you cant output the function inside the same function.

Comment: i removed the console.log as this was only for testing purposes. I still get the NaN message on the output. Allready tried to parseInt the strings but that also doesn't do the trick.

Comment: I can't produce any result using your sample. Create an example that we can execute to give the result you've described in your question.

Comment: With " still get the NaN message on the output." .. on what position is that?

Comment: The NaN message is shown at <div id="totalPrice"></div> (almost the end of the form script)

Comment: Can you debug 

var total = 29.95 + getPootPrijs(poot) + getKleurPrijs(kleur);

So break it down to 2 vars for getPootPrijs(poot)  and getKleurPrijs(kleur) so you can console log that. Maybe one of the functions returns a NaN. Also console log poot and kleur.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it with a workarround.

In the form i changed the onclick to `onclick="poot=10;calculateTotal();"` the 10 number is the added value to the standard price.

```html
<div class="row setup-content-3" id="step-5">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h3 class="font-weight-bold pl-0 my-4"><strong>Soort Poot</strong></h3>
                <div class="form-group md-form">
                          <ul>
                            <li2>
                                <input type='radio' value='poot1' name='selectedOption' id='poot1' required/>
                                <label for='poot1'><img src="bed1.jpg" style="height: 100px;" onclick="poot=10;calculateTotal();"></img></label>
                              </li2>
                        <li2>
                                <input type='radio' value='poot2' name='selectedOption' id='poot2'/>
                                <label for='poot2'><img src="bed2.jpg" style="height: 100px;" onclick="poot=20;calculateTotal();"></img></label>
                              </li2>
                        <li2>
                                <input type='radio' value='poot3' name='selectedOption' id='poot3'/>
                                <label for='poot3'><img src="bed3.jpg" style="height: 100px;" onclick="poot=30;calculateTotal();"></img></label>
                            </li2>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-rounded nextBtn-3 float-right" type="button">Volgende</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And i changed javascript to a much simpeler script.

```js
var poot = 0;
var kleur = 0;
var breedte = 0;
var lengte = 0;

function calculateTotal() {
var total = 29.95 + poot + kleur + breedte + lengte;
var totalEl = document.getElementById('totalPrice');

document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "Totale prijs: €" + total;
totalEl.style.display = 'block';
}
```

with `<div id="totalPrice"></div>` i show the price on the form. Thanks for everyone who tried to answer this question!